# Deleting row with a blank column value

Tags: sql

I have a person table in SQL and i have columns: id, lastname, firstname, address, city.
City for a person is empty so i want a query to delete the row containing the person with a blank city column value. The code below didn't do it even though no errors were raised.

```
DELETE FROM persons pers
WHERE lastname = 'saire' AND address = 'NULL'
```

Comment: Don't use `field = 'NULL'` unless you want to find a field whose value is the string `'NULL'`. Use `IS NULL` instead, eg: `DELETE FROM Persons WHERE lastname = 'saire' AND address IS NULL`. This question has been asked many times before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following SQL command should remove all records with a null value for city. Try this.

```
DELETE FROM persons
where city IS NULL
```

Comment: You can't alias a delete table like that.  Proper syntax would be `delete from pers from persons as pers where ...`

Answer (score 0):

```
$q = "DELETE FROM `table_name` WHERE `city` =''";
```